# How to POST file upload after returning to view from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, file-upload

I can successfully upload a file (path stored in database, and file moved to file storage location).  However, if validation fails for another field in the view and the user is returned to the view page, the file input displays "No File Chosen".

In debug, when the controller returns to the view, this.Model.CoverLetter is "System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper".

How do I preserve this file so that it can be re-submitted via POST?  Do I need to do something in the controller in order to pass the file information back to the view for re-submission?

View:

```
<label for="CoverLetter">Cover Letter</label>
<input type="file" name="CoverLetter" id="CoverLetter" accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx,.txt" />
@Html.ValidationMessage("CoverLetter")
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Applicant application, HttpPostedFileBase CoverLetter)
{
     this.ModelState.AddModelErrors(application.Validate(update: false));

     if (this.ModelState.IsValid && application.Create())
     {
          //this stuff works
     }
     return View(application);
}
```

Comment: do client side validation, is jquery uobtrusive validate included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the value of a input type file programatically for security reasons. It's simply not allowed.

The best you can do is to validate on client side where possible and do an ajax validation for those things that need to be validated on server side.